# Default value for Create form in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I would like to set a default value of a text area in my asp.net mvc 5 application. I have a field in my Patient model that looks like this:

```
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

and i would like to set the default value of this field to the current date. 
Right now it is displaying this form : http://scr.hu/11m6/lf9d5 .
I have already tried using the constructor and setting the value of DateOfBirth in it :

```
    public Patient()
    {
        DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

but it had no effect. I also tried editing my view .cshtml file to this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @value = "2014-05-05" })
```

but it also had no effect. Does anyone know a solution to this ?

Comment: Add your controller code

Comment: It's very odd that that isn't working. I just threw together a real quick test. I created a Patient.cs, put your property on it, added your constructor, and scaffolded a Controller and View and when the view comes up it has today's date in the DateOfBirth field.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4f3arE2d - controller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should create an instance of `Patient` class and pass it to the view in your `Create` action. In your case view model is not set, so it does not enters `Patient` class constructor and does not use `DateTime.Now` value to be displayed.

Try changing your `Create` action method from:

```
    // GET: /Patient/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

to:

```
    // GET: /Patient/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var patient = new Patient();
        return View(patient);
    }
```

Comment: That was the case. Thanks :)